# Branched covers of the sphere branched over few points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface of genus $g\geq 2$. By the Riemann-Roch theorem, $X$ is a branched cover of the sphere, branched over finitely many branched values. What is the smallest number of such values, for general $X$ of genus $g$?

Since moduli space has complex dimension $3g-3$, and branched covers branched over $B$ points are contained in the union of countably many varieties of dimension at most $B-3$, for general $X$ we need at least $3g$ branched values.

Riemann-Roch shows that there is a holomorphic $X\to\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ of degree $g+1$ having a single pole, of degree $g+1$. By Riemann-Hurwitz, this function has $4g$ critical points, of which $g$ are over infinity. So in total there are at most $3g+1$ critical values. So my question becomes:

**Question.** Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface of genus $g\geq 2$. Is there a holomorphic function $f\colon X\to \hat{\mathbb{C}}$ which has at most $3g$ critical values?

It is plausible that the answer is positive, but in either case the answer is surely known. Does anyone know a reference?

I have been told that Brill-Noether theory shows the existence of a meromorphic function of degree $\lfloor(g+3)/2\rfloor$ on $X$. For even $g$, applying Riemann-Hurwitz then shows that there are $3g$ critical points for this function. That answers the question in the positive for even $g$. But for odd $g$, we get the same number $3g+1$ as via Riemann-Roch.

Comment: You just need to apply your argument with a Weierstrass point — that is a point $p$ for which there exists a meromorphic function with a pole of order  $k\leq g$ at $p$ (they always exist). Then the number of critical values is at most $2g+k\leq 3g$.

Comment: @abx Thanks! Alex Eremenko just pointed out the same thing to me. :D Do you want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me post my comment as an answer. Take a Weierstrass point on $X$,  that is, a point  $P$ for which there exists a meromorphic function $f$ with a pole of order $k\leq g$ at $P$ (there always exists such a point). Then apply the argument in the post: by Riemann-Hurwitz the number of critical points of $f$, counted with multiplicity, is $2g-2+2k$. But $P$ appears with multiplicity $k-1$ in this count, so the number of critical values outside $\infty$ is $\leq 2g-2+2k-(k-1)=2g+k-1$, and the total number  of critical values is $\leq 2g+k\leq 3g$.

Comment: Do you think that for each $g$ and each $0<k<3g-3$ (i.e. avoiding this case and Belyi case) it's open whether every curve of genus $g$ defined over an algebraically closed field of transcendence degree $k$ has a map to $\mathbb P^1$ branched over at most $k+3$ points?

Comment: @Will Sawin: Very interesting question! Unfortunately I have no idea...